# Why "receive / transmit bytes" is so big difference between optical modem and host when download data on host?

Tags: debian, networking, embedded, modem

ens33 is my host network card,it show a normal number as my network use status,but I don't know why my modem show a very small data traffic in all interfaces of modem when download on host.

My host:

```
$ cat /proc/net/dev
Inter-|   Receive                                                |  Transmit
 face |bytes    packets errs drop fifo frame compressed multicast|bytes    packets errs drop fifo colls carrier compressed
    lo: 29814737   43314    0    0    0     0          0         0 29814737   43314    0    0    0     0       0          0
  ppp0: 466128413  324635    0    0    0     0          0         0  9899183  172128    0    0    0     0       0          0
 ens33: 527070502  406968    0    0    0     0          0         0 23141644  246355    0    0    0     0       0          0
$
```

My optical modem:

```
WAP(Dopra Linux) # cat /proc/net/dev
Inter-|   Receive                                                |  Transmit
 face |bytes    packets errs drop fifo frame compressed multicast|bytes    packets errs drop fifo colls carrier compressed
    lo:  191600    1304    0    0    0     0          0         0   191600    1304    0    0    0     0       0          0
  eth0:  454167    5058    0    0    0     0          0         0  1369093    6227    0    0    0     0       0          0
   br0:  357095    4935    0    0    0     0          0       136  1244249    4036    0    0    0     0       0          0
  wan1:       0       0    0    0    0     0          0         0    89976    1956    0    0    0     0       0          0
  wan2:       0       0    0    0    0     0          0         0        0       0    0    0    0     0       0          0
  wan3:       0       0    0    0    0     0          0         0     3672     102    0    0    0     0       0          0
WAP(Dopra Linux) #
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't even know what numbers to look at here. What are the interfaces you're using? How do you know that the numbers only refer to the downloading of the same data?

Comment: I reword my question ,now is make sense to you? @Kusalananda

Comment: I'm sorry,but I again reword my question. Is make sense to you ? please. @Kusalananda

Comment: The numbers are reset at boot?

Comment: When I download on host ,modern is never reboot and keep a telnet connect. @MurrayJensen